# Why German language cannot search out some special English word in full text index search

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Create test table at first

```
create table testFullIndexSearch(pk int identity constraint tfispk primary key, displayName varchar(100))
GO
create fulltext catalog test1 as default
GO
create fulltext index on testFullIndexSearch(displayName) key index tfispk
GO
insert into testFullIndexSearch(displayName) values('sharepoint')
insert into testFullIndexSearch(displayName) values('share')
insert into testFullIndexSearch(displayName) values('point')
GO
```

the language of displayName in full text index is English.
Then I am using below query to search

```
 select * from testFullIndexSearch t inner join 
 CONTAINSTABLE(testFullIndexSearch, *, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "Sharepoint")', LANGUAGE 1031) as w on t.pk=w.[Key]
```

There is nothing return. But we use parser to analysis the keyword

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"Sharepoint"', 1031, 0, 0)--1031 German
```

we should get 3 records include sharepoint, share and point.
so why we cannot search out records in containstable for Sharepoint in German language.
for other language such Spanish or French etc are all work.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Sorry, nope. it's a legacy issue for me. and I cannot reproduce this issue any more.

Answer (score 0):

If you index the column in english but search with german you may have different situation.

Indexing the word "sharepoint" will put the keyword "sharepoint" into the column index.

Search the word "sharepoint" as german will split the word into "share" and "point" and look for those words in the index table.

> You will have to indexing the column as german

Additionally it could occur that even indexed as german, you search a indexed keyword but don't get any match. This occurs if the search phrase gets splitted into additional keywords (by the german word breaker) which are missing in the index.

Check out this for detailed information about this issue:
https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/5eedef49-53a1-ed11-a81b-6045bd79fc6e

As alternative you can index as german but search in english.